# How to save Scikit-Learn-Keras model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to save the trained model into my disk. As far as I know, I can save the model using the following code:

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

However I am using `keras classifier` and `kfold` and fitting the model in the background, my code is:

```
def baseline_model(optimizer='adam', init='random_uniform'):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=18260, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=init))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=init))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer=init))
    model.summary()
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, validation_split=0.33, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

How can I save the trained model in this case?
Also, if I want to make predictions, how to do that given that I don't have the fitted model?

Comment: K-Fold CV is meant to evaluate a model, not to train a model for you to use it after, that's why you can save a model in this case, as it makes no sense. Which one of the 10 models would you save?

Comment: But the model fitting is happening in the background right? I mean if no, then how does the accuracy increase/decrease?

Comment: Yes, of course, models are fit to the folds in the background.

Comment: Then how can I save anything that can be loaded later on so I can make predictions without rerunning the whole compilation?

Comment: Don't use K-Fold CV and just train a model in your data. You don't need scikit-learn for this.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Just to nitpick on your comment, one could indeed first cross-validate the model to tune some hyperparameters and then eventually save the one giving the best validation (or test) score: that's for example what people do with `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: @gented Yes but its not the same to train a model using K-Fold CV and try to save one of those models, than to only learn the hyper-parameters and then train a model on the full data with those hyper-parameters.